# Problems understanding Parameters

Tags: c#, parameters

```
public int GiveCash(int amount) {
    if (amount <= Cash && amount > 0) {
        Cash -= amount;
        return amount;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I create a method `GiveCash`, and pass the parameter `amount`.  What is that doing? Why am I not just using a variable?  I am just having trouble understanding what it is I just coded. What is a Parameter and what is it doing?

Comment: It's the input to the method. It can be a variable. You pass a variable (or just a value that matches the type--in this case `int`) in as a parameter to the method so the method can use it to do stuff

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep reading the book...

Comment: I would start with a google search for example `C# Method Parameters` I bet you will see many articles and awesome examples

Comment: What would you return if `amount <= Cash && amount > 0` is false?

Answer (score 1):

When you call your `GiveCash` method, you decide how much cash you want to get as you see fit, for example

```
int lastMonth = 12;
var newValue = myObject.GiveCash(lastMonth*2 + 5);
```

You need to tell `GiveCash` how much cash you need by passing it an `int` number. You compute the required cash using an expression `lastMonth*2 + 5`.

Now `GetCash` method needs to refer to the value computed by the caller in some way. Formal parameters provide a way to do it: C# computes the value of the expression, and assigns it to an `int` variable `amount`, called a *method parameter*. This variable is designated for the exclusive use of the `GiveCash` method; as soon as the method finishes execution, this variable disappears. That is how the caller communicates the inputs to methods that it calls.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! It's just even after finishing the chapter I was struggling to understand what that was, thanks!